# Creating a Lisp alias with defalias or new function?

Tags: function, lisp, elisp, alias

I want `mylist` to have the same functionality as `list`. In most Lisps (I'm on Emacs Lisp) I can simply write

```
(defalias 'mylist 'list)
```

But if I want to write my own I can write

```
(defun mylist (&rest x)
    (car (list x)))
```

which has the same functionality. But then I got this by experimenting. First, I had this code

```
(defun mylist (&rest x)
        (list x))
```

which produced a list in a list. I wasn't sure why, but the simple solution was to just put `(list x)` inside a `car` and call it good. But I'd like to know why I get a list inside a list when I don't use the `car` trick. What am I missing?

Comment: Most lisps do not have a `defalias` out-of-the-box. It's an Emacs Lisp feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `(defun my-list (&rest x) …`

The `&rest` parameter means that all remaining arguments are put into a list that is bound to this parameter.  `X` then holds the list that you want.  You're done.

```
(defun my-list (&rest x)
  x)
```

Comment: The usual interface contract for `list` says that the resulting list cells are freshly allocated. Only the caller has a reference to them and may destructively manipulate them without having an uintended effect elsewhere. Does this hold about a list that was produced from function arguments under the `&rest` mechanism?

Comment: Suppose we call `(apply 'my-list existing-list)`. Is that required to return a fresh list?

Comment: @Kaz: yes, this might share structure, so in order to fulfill that contract, `my-list` would need to `(copy-list x)`.  I conciously tried to keep the answer as simple as possible, in order to match the level of the question.  I'll think about this.

Answer (score 3):

> But if I want to write my own I can write
>
> (defun mylist (&rest x)
>       (car (list x)))

But why?

```
3 -> 3
(list 3) -> (3)
(car (list 3)) -> 3
```

So `(car (list arg))` is a no-op on `arg`.

Thus it's just:

```
(defun mylist (&rest x)
  x)
```

> But I'd like to know why I get a list inside a list when I don't use the car trick. What am I missing?

if you have a list

```
x -> (1 2 3)
```

and call `list` on it

```
(list x) -> ((1 2 3))
```

Then you get a list in a list.

Calling `car` on a list is also not a *trick*. It's returning the first element of that list:

```
(car (list x)) -> (1 2 3)
```

Comment: So as Svante points out, I missed the fine print (Kleingedrucktes) on exactly what using `&rest` does, namely, it *bundles* all arguments into a list, i.e., no need to even call `list` in the body.

Comment: @147pm That is not obvious at all. Optimizations of `&rest` parameter passing can elide the construction of a new list, like when an existing list is `apply`-ed.

Comment: @147pm: I wonder what you expected.  If `(list x)` always produces a list with a single element, how is it supposed to magically recognize this special `x` as something coming from a `&rest` parameter that it is supposed to unwrap before re-wrapping?  That rest parameters give lists is not the fine print but the main contract.